# Using ` symbol for concatenations in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

On a new project, I've seen that someone is doing a string concatenation in components using the **`** symbol (ASCII 96 or grave accent symbol):

```
let a = `${this.SOME_CONSTANT}/some_string/${some_variable.some_property}`;
```

Is this considered a normal practice in Angular 5 instead of using normal plusses? Isn't this a template creation operation thus should work slower?

Comment: This is not a concatenation symbol it';s called string template literal and it's part of es6 specification.

Comment: es-linter prefer string template literal over normal plusses for concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called `template string` it came new in `Ecma Script 6`. This way you can use variables and do calculations within the string when you use `${}`.

Personally I like the template strings, but you have to keep in mind, that Internet Explorer can't compile it. If your application has to run on `IE` than you can't use it (https://caniuse.com/#search=template%20string).

Comment: Thank you, I thought this is some Angular 5 feature. Is there any profit in using it, besides tagging and multiline support?

Comment: It is shorter and in my opinion better to read. A line like this `"Fifteen is " + (a + b) + " and\nnot " + (2 * a + b) + "."` would be `\`Fifteen is ${a + b} and\nnot ${2 * a + b}.\``. You don't need the extra `"` and `+`

Answer (score 2):

To use special characters in a string sometimes the simple `' '` won't work.